# How to distinguish between commits in stacked pull requests

Tags: git, gitlab

I am working on building out the documentation site on a github repo, which involves a lot of file changes and new files. To simplify the review, I wanted to break up the big feature branch into smaller PRs. I was just trying to figure out how to practically manage this.

I am following [this post](https://blog.logrocket.com/using-stacked-pull-requests-in-github/), that shows how to break up a large pull request into stacked pull requests. The idea is to checkout a branch `new_feature` from `master`, then implement some changes and open a PR against this branch. Next I checkout a new branch `new_feature_p2` starting from `new_feature` and make some more changes and create a PR against `new_feature_p2`.

The question is, when I go to github and I try to create the PR for `new_feature_p2`, I can still see the commit for the original `new_feature` branch. I am not sure if that is okay, or if I need to change something so that I don't recommit the same files in the second PR.

Note that I forked the original repository, so I am submitting changes off of the fork. Will those common commits from PR1 and PR2 disappear once PR1 is approved? Then PR2 will just go in without any changes to the PR1 files?

Or is there some better way to handle this process.

Comment: Unfortunately, the only real identity of a commit is its commit hash ID. If your workflow involves doing rebase or squash operations, that identity is *lost*. There's a secondary identity, `git patch-id`, that is usable for *some* rebase cases, but it's much less reliable. Making all of this work smoothly is probably impossible, otherwise GitLaHubucket would already do it. But feel free to work on the problem! 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The question is, when I go to github and I try to create the PR for new_feature_p2, I can still see the commit for the original new_feature branch

Because you forgot to repoint the second PR's target branch (the one you're merging into) at the original `new_feature` branch.

---

Okay, that's not quite accurate, because we're talking about how the second PR is seen back on the *original* repo. The answer there, I think, is that your intuition here is correct:

> Will those common commits from PR1 and PR2 disappear once PR1 is approved? Then PR2 will just go in without any changes to the PR1 files?

Yes. What's shown in PR2 is simply a calculated diff between this branch and the main branch. Once PR1 is merged into the main branch on the original repo, things that are present in PR2 merely because they were present in PR1 will no longer be different between PR2 and `main`, and so PR2 will look the right way.

As I say in my comment, perhaps the most helpful strategy for the owners of the original repo would be for you to go ahead and divide your work into branches but don't even submit the next PR until the prior PR has been merged. That way, the overlords of the original repo always see only the minimum material in each PR, which was your goal all along.

Comment: okay, so let me just clarify. If I point the target branch of the second PR to the `new_feature` branch, then it should work. But note that the `new_feature` branch has not been merged yet, so it is not on the list of branches in the original repo. The `new_feature` branch only exists in my forked repo. So how would I specify the proper target branch as `new_feature`?

Comment: I suppose the fork adds a complication.

Comment: I had to fork, because I don't have permissions on the original repo. So I can't save my branch up to the original repo and then submit my PR from the original repo. Do you have any thoughts on how to handle this?

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you're doing. Obviously the branches are in your fork. But what about the PRs? Are you submitting these PRs in your fork or in the original repo?

Comment: Ahh. So I forked the repo, then worked on the code and saved my local branch to the forked repo. From the forked repo I submitted a PR against the original repo. So I want to merge a commit TO the `original repo:master` FROM `my-fork:my_branch`. The change is like 18 files, so instead of making a huge and difficult to review PR, I tried to break it up into a few files at a time. So the next PR will be another branch from `my-fork:my_branch_2` to `original_repo:master`, but it depends upon `my_branch` being merged first. Does that clarify?

Comment: I mean if there is a better way to do something like this, please let me know. The dependencies between subsequent PRs is rather minimial. For example, I create a `docs` folder in `my_branch_1` and then in PR 2, on `my_branch_2` I add some files to that folder. So the first PR creates the folder (among other things), and the second PR adds some additional files to that folder. I could do all 18 file changes at once, but seems like that will be hard to review.

Comment: Yes, I suspect that in _that_ case you simply have to wait until `my_branch` _is_ merged at the original repo. At that point, the changes from `my_branch` will vanish from the diff shown in `my_branch_2`. Basically, the trick you were trying to use here (from the linked blog) doesn't work all that well in a fork-and-PR-to-the-original situation, but nothing stops you from using it, because in the end a merge is just a merge, a diff is just a diff, etc.

Comment: Just make it clear to your Benevolent Overlords that they shouldn't even _look_ at the second PR until the first one is merged. But even better, I would say, is that _you_ don't even submit the second PR until the first one is merged. Nothing prevents you from lining up the branches in advance on your fork, ready to rock and roll!

Comment: Modified my answer to account for all that. Let me know if you want to discuss further in chat.

Comment: Okay, I got you now @matt. Thanks for the detailed and very specific advice. Yeah, I can do as you say. I can just stack up the branches locally and then communicate with the owners on the pacing of submission. Luckily the packages is pretty new, so like 10 people know about it :). Also good to know that the changes from the previous branch will disappear from the subsequent PRs, as the changes from the previous branches get merged. So that is also good to know. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. Do let me know if any doubts / issues remain. — What I do in my real life, sometimes, is this: I line up branches that depend on one another. When branch A gets merged into the main branch, I _rebase_ branch B onto the main branch, and submit it. This works safely because branch B was _private to me_ until _after_ I rebased it. And so forth.

Comment: Similarly, if the Overlords call for changes on branch A, you will want to rebase branch B onto the _new_ branch A to pick up whatever you do to satisfy those demands. Just stay nimble and keep track of your relationships and you'll be fine. I find notes on a piece of paper to be quite helpful!